# What do I do in the glass box in The Chase?

Tags: antichamber

In *The Chase*, I followed the black ghost thing through the level until I got to a point where the only path I can see leads to a glass box. When I walk into the box and turn around, I am surrounded by glass on all sides and I can see the ghost moving outside of the box. The ghost sighting seems to indicate I was supposed to go there, but once I am in the box I can't figure out what to do next. What am I supposed to do one I enter the glass box?

Comment: Can you remember the last time you saw a white loop? What did you do then?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. If you are talking about the white circles on the walls, I don't remember where I saw one before the one *in* the glass box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Face the white ring. Then move backwards.